# Annotate one of the constructors for a class with non-nullable parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, constructor, mapstruct

I want to use MapStruct to create a mapper from Kotlin Code. The mapper should map to the class with non-nullable fields.

```
data class TargetClass(val nonNullable: String, var canBeNullable: Int? = null)
```

For that I would expect MapStruct use constructor:

```
TargetClass targetClass = new TargetClass("someString");
targetClass.setCanBeNullable = 3;
```

With MapStruct I believe I can do it by annotating one of the constructors with `@Default` annotation. I can annotate the whole with `@JvmOverloads` and get many versions of constructors in Java but how could I annotate the specific one?

Comment: Just write an extra secondary constructor and annotate that. That's not a lot of code, is it?

Comment: Well it is possible, but a little tedious if we have classes having more than 20 fields. But probably there will be no better option :) Thanks